# How can I create a TIMESTAMP column in HIVE with a string based timestamp?

Tags: hive, hiveql, trino

I am attempting to create a table in HIVE so that it can be queried via Trino .. but getting an error. My guess is I need to transform or somehow modify the string or do something with the formatting?  do I do that at the `CREATE TABLE` step?  no idea

[image]

[image]

```
use hive.MYSCHEMA;
USE
trino:MYSCHEMA> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hive.MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE (
           ->                  column_1           VARCHAR,
           ->                  column_2           VARCHAR,
           ->                  column_3           VARCHAR,
           ->                  column_4           BIGINT,
           ->                  column_5           VARCHAR,
           ->                  column_6           VARCHAR,
           ->                  query_start_time   TIMESTAMP)
           ->                WITH (
           ->                  external_location = 's3a://MYS3BUCKET/dir1/dir2/',
           ->                  format = 'PARQUET');
CREATE TABLE
trino:MYSCHEMA> SELECT * FROM MYTABLE;

Query 20220926_131538_00008_dbc39, FAILED, 1 node
Splits: 1 total, 0 done (0.00%)
1.72 [0 rows, 0B] [0 rows/s, 0B/s]

Query 20220926_131538_00008_dbc39 failed: Failed to read Parquet file: s3a://MYS3BUCKET/dir1/dir2/20220918_194105-135895.snappy.parquet
```

the full stacktrace is as follows

```
io.trino.spi.TrinoException: Failed to read Parquet file: s3a://MYS3BUCKET/dir1/dir2/20220918_194105-135895.snappy.parquet
    at io.trino.plugin.hive.parquet.ParquetPageSource.handleException(ParquetPageSource.java:169)
    at io.trino.plugin.hive.parquet.ParquetPageSourceFactory.lambda$createPageSource$6(ParquetPageSourceFactory.java:271)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetBlockFactory$ParquetBlockLoader.load(ParquetBlockFactory.java:75)
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock$LazyData.load(LazyBlock.java:406)
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock$LazyData.getFullyLoadedBlock(LazyBlock.java:385)
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock.getLoadedBlock(LazyBlock.java:292)
    at io.trino.spi.Page.getLoadedPage(Page.java:229)
    at io.trino.operator.TableScanOperator.getOutput(TableScanOperator.java:314)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.processInternal(Driver.java:411)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.lambda$process$10(Driver.java:314)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.tryWithLock(Driver.java:706)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.process(Driver.java:306)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.processForDuration(Driver.java:277)
    at io.trino.execution.SqlTaskExecution$DriverSplitRunner.processFor(SqlTaskExecution.java:736)
    at io.trino.execution.executor.PrioritizedSplitRunner.process(PrioritizedSplitRunner.java:164)
    at io.trino.execution.executor.TaskExecutor$TaskRunner.run(TaskExecutor.java:515)
    at io.trino.$gen.Trino_397____20220926_094436_2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: io.trino.spi.type.ShortTimestampType
    at io.trino.spi.type.AbstractType.writeSlice(AbstractType.java:115)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.BinaryColumnReader.readValue(BinaryColumnReader.java:54)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.PrimitiveColumnReader.lambda$readValues$2(PrimitiveColumnReader.java:248)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.PrimitiveColumnReader.processValues(PrimitiveColumnReader.java:304)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.PrimitiveColumnReader.readValues(PrimitiveColumnReader.java:246)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.PrimitiveColumnReader.readPrimitive(PrimitiveColumnReader.java:235)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.readPrimitive(ParquetReader.java:441)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.readColumnChunk(ParquetReader.java:540)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.readBlock(ParquetReader.java:523)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.lambda$nextPage$3(ParquetReader.java:272)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetBlockFactory$ParquetBlockLoader.load(ParquetBlockFactory.java:72)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: To verify if the TIMESTAMP column is really the issue, exclude the query_start_time column from the CREATE statement and see if it allows you to query the table.

Comment: I indeed did that @glory9211 and things were fine.. if I use `VARCHAR` on the column it also loads just fine ... but I was hoping to get native timestamp columns

Comment: it will not auto convert string data 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mi:ss:sss' to a timestamp. So, you need to store it as a string and then convert to a timestamp using a SQL. You can store data into another table as a timestamp from this table after conversion.

Comment: Thank you @KoushikRoy would you mind posting an example?  When I tried creating the tables they failed.. I can see many many examples of `SELECT` using the conversion.. but never any table examples.

Comment: also @KoushikRoy if I can .. what format WOULD HIVE take natively? for `TIMESTAMP` ?

Comment: Can you share if the query_start_time column has data in unix_timestamp format(bigint) or string date format (yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss:sss) ?
It will be helpful if you could share the sample data/format in the column

Comment: @glory9211 added thumbnail in post.. I hope that is what you meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve the desired results by splitting the task into 2 steps. Hive does not have a feature to transform a string to the timestamp in DDL.

So first we create 2 tables.

Fist we create the original table with the data

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
    hive.MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE (
        column_1           VARCHAR,
        column_2           VARCHAR,
        column_3           VARCHAR,
        column_4           BIGINT,
        column_5           VARCHAR,
        column_6           VARCHAR,
        query_start_time   VARCHAR)
    WITH (
        external_location = 's3a://MYS3BUCKET/dir1/dir2/',
        format = 'PARQUET');
```

Next the new table with correct timestamp data type

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
    hive.MYSCHEMA.NEWTABLE (
        column_1           VARCHAR,
        column_2           VARCHAR,
        column_3           VARCHAR,
        column_4           BIGINT,
        column_5           VARCHAR,
        column_6           VARCHAR,
        query_start_time   TIMESTAMP)
    WITH (
        external_location = 's3a://MYS3BUCKET/newlocation/',
        format = 'PARQUET');
```

Now we move data from MYTABLE to NEWTABLE with conversion using

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE NEWTABLE Select column_1, column_2, column_3, ...., column_6,
unix_timestamp(query_start_time, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ') as query_start_time from MYTABLE;
```

You will have to test for the correct format in the unix_timestamp function by reading [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions)

This will first convert the string column to timestamp and then store it in the new table. This means that all the old data will be read and stored in the new location.
You can think of it as an ETL job in Hive.

***Additional Information to Why this conversion needs ETL although we have Schema ON Read***

Schema ON Read is powerful for Big Data. It allows you to change the data type of a column stored in data while reading.
For example, you have the `ID` column as `INT` in your file but you can read it as `STRING/VARCHAR` if you define the column type as a string in your DDL.
Similarly reading a `TIMESTAMP` data as `DATETIME`. This is useful for schema evolution or reading from multiple sources with different datatypes.

Now why we couldn't use this power in the above scenario?

This will be the case for every scenario where you want to process the column. e.g. split one string column into two columns. The reason why we have to perform ETL, in this case, is because in parquet/avro timestamp datatype is not a primitive type. It is of type long int and with the additional property of logical_type as datetime/timestamp.
You can read [here-parquet](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md) and [here-avro](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/spec.html#Logical+Types) about logical types for further clarification.

Comment: If I have the power to... change the data .. I will look into simply switching to whatever native format HIVE supports.. so as to avoid the need for new tables .. but this is great to know thank you!

Comment: I have added some more details to the answer. Will be happy to know if someone finds a  good way to convert into timestamp parquet directly from string since it will help solve the extra processing effort.

Answer (score 1):

Hive will take below format natively. So, if you can remove T and Z I think you should be good to go.
Please give bellow CT sql a try. This may not be a parquet table but it should work if your timestamp is in correct string format.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id int,
  ts timestamp)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
'serialization.format' = ',',
'field.delim' = ',',
"timestamp.formats"="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
)
LOCATION 's3://user/'
```

Comment: did a quick test where I simply removed the `Z` , but was met with a `Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: io.trino.spi.type.ShortTimestampType` exception

Comment: using your syntax I also saw this `failed: line 9:1: mismatched input 'ROW'. Expecting: 'COMMENT', 'WITH', <EOF>`, thank you though

Comment: I think you need to remove both T and Z

Comment: ah of course! let me retry again

Comment: hmm even taking out the Z and T .. yields the same error